# How do I get the result of 3 random numbers using random operator?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I have trying to get the result of the 3 random number using random operators. This is what have done so far. Could anyone explain or show how i can do this

```
fun rightEquation(){

        var num5 = 1 + generator.nextInt(20)
        var num6 = 1 + generator.nextInt(20)
        var num7 = 1 + generator.nextInt(20)
        var num8 = 1 + generator.nextInt(20)

        var total = mutableListOf<String>()

        eq5 = "(" + num5 + "" + operation() + "" + num6 + ")" + operation() + "" + num7

    }

 fun operation(): String {

        return when (generator.nextInt(4)){
            0 -> "-"
            1 -> "+"
            2 -> "/"
            3 -> "*"
            else ->""
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Kotlin 1.3, there’s a built-in method to fetch a random item from a list: **random()**

```
fun rightEquation(): String {
  return "(${randomNumber()}${randomOperator()}${randomNumber()})${randomOperator()}${randomNumber()}"
}    

fun randomOperator(): String {
  val operators = listOf("-", "+", "/", "*")
  return operators.random()
}

fun randomNumber(): String {
   val number = 1 + generator.nextInt(20)
   return number.toString()
}
```

Comment: ok, i just implemented that but how to i get the result of the 3 random random using random equation.

Comment: check the updated answer

Comment: Could you explain how it works

Answer (score 0):

This will generate an equation and calculate the result of it:

```
fun evaluate(str: String): Double {

  data class Data(val rest: List<Char>, val value: Double)

  return object : Any() {

    fun parse(chars: List<Char>): Double {
      return getExpression(chars.filter { it != ' ' })
        .also { if (it.rest.isNotEmpty()) throw RuntimeException("Unexpected character: ${it.rest.first()}") }
        .value
    }

    private fun getExpression(chars: List<Char>): Data {
      var (rest, carry) = getTerm(chars)
      while (true) {
        when {
          rest.firstOrNull() == '+' -> rest = getTerm(rest.drop(1)).also { carry += it.value }.rest
          rest.firstOrNull() == '-' -> rest = getTerm(rest.drop(1)).also { carry -= it.value }.rest
          else                      -> return Data(rest, carry)
        }
      }
    }

    fun getTerm(chars: List<Char>): Data {
      var (rest, carry) = getFactor(chars)
      while (true) {
        when {
          rest.firstOrNull() == '*' -> rest = getTerm(rest.drop(1)).also { carry *= it.value }.rest
          rest.firstOrNull() == '/' -> rest = getTerm(rest.drop(1)).also { carry /= it.value }.rest
          else                      -> return Data(rest, carry)
        }
      }
    }

    fun getFactor(chars: List<Char>): Data {
      return when (val char = chars.firstOrNull()) {
        '+'              -> getFactor(chars.drop(1)).let { Data(it.rest, +it.value) }
        '-'              -> getFactor(chars.drop(1)).let { Data(it.rest, -it.value) }
        '('              -> getParenthesizedExpression(chars.drop(1))
        in '0'..'9', ',' -> getNumber(chars)
        else             -> throw RuntimeException("Unexpected character: $char")
      }
    }

    fun getParenthesizedExpression(chars: List<Char>): Data {
      return getExpression(chars)
        .also { if (it.rest.firstOrNull() != ')') throw RuntimeException("Missing closing parenthesis") }
        .let { Data(it.rest.drop(1), it.value) }
    }

    fun getNumber(chars: List<Char>): Data {
      val s = chars.takeWhile { it.isDigit() || it == '.' }.joinToString("")
      return Data(chars.drop(s.length), s.toDouble())
    }

  }.parse(str.toList())

}

val num1 = (1..20).random()
val num2 = (1..20).random()
val num3 = (1..20).random()
val op1 = listOf('+', '-', '*', '/').random()
val op2 = listOf('+', '-', '*', '/').random()

val equation = "( $num1 $op1 $num2 ) $op2 $num3"

println("$equation = ${evaluate(equation)}")
```